# Calculating subnet mask

Tags: networking, ip, subnet

I have problem calculating a subnet mask.

Suppose xyz college is planning to setup a small private network with network address `192.168.20.0`. The number of departments in the college are 7 and the max no. of host in each department is 25. How to calculate subnet mask?

When I tried to google to find a tutorial for calculating such kind of problems, got nothing.

Comment: Lot of online subnet mask calculator are there? Eg: http://www.subnet-calculator.com/

Comment: @ritesh_nitw Was not looking for a auto calc. atleast.

Comment: Please do not wrap non-code in code tags.

Answer (score 2):

A mask of /27 will give you 5 bits for the host ip addresses and 5 bits will be enough to represent 25 hosts. Each department can go on a different network, eg: Dept A can be 192.168.20.0/27 and Dept B can be 192.168.21.0/27 etc...

Answer (score 2):

I realize this question is 2 years old but thought I'd add to it if others come here with a homework problem similar to this one. Assuming that each network never needs more than 30 hosts, (it states that 25 will be the most) then you could use 5 host bits and 27 subnet identifier bits for each network.

5 bits can represent 30 hosts because:

- 2^5 = 32

So 32 numbers can be represented with 5 binary bits.

Subtract 2 because the lowest address in each subnet is the network address while the highest address is the broadcast

- 32-2=30 assignable addresses

4 bits would not have been enough as (2^4)-2=14.

If you go with more bits, you'll have larger gaps between subnets and potentially wasted addresses.

Generally, these are assigned as the lowest available addresses (at least they will be for the sake of your homework).

192.168.20.0 in binary = 11000000.10101000.00010100.00000000

While sashang's answer works, if this is homework, your professor will be looking for you to update the right most subnet identifier (or network identifier) bits first. We know there are 27 bits in the subnet identifier from the "/27" in CIDR notation. They are the first 27 bits in bold below.

**11000000.10101000.00010100.000**00000

If you increment from the far right and make 7 subnets, here's the subnet addresses you would get. I'll just bold the binary digits that will change and not the rest of the network address to the left.

11000000.10101000.00010100.**000**00000 = 192.168.20.0/27
11000000.10101000.00010100.**001**00000 = 192.168.20.32/27
11000000.10101000.00010100.**010**00000 = 192.168.20.64/27
11000000.10101000.00010100.**011**00000 = 192.168.20.96/27
11000000.10101000.00010100.**100**00000 = 192.168.20.128/27
11000000.10101000.00010100.**101**00000 = 192.168.20.160/27
11000000.10101000.00010100.**110**00000 = 192.168.20.192/27